# Getting rid of extraneous details in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I made a mistake working on an excel list of product descriptions and now some of the products have their part number listed twice. It is formatted like "[product number], [product number]" and I need to get rid of that second product number after the comma. Product numbers aren't the same length so I can't use right(x), and all the part numbers are different, so I can't think of any way I can't use find/replace. Is there any way to automate this quickly?

Comment: Are the duplicates the only part numbers who include a comma?

Comment: The part numbers don't include a comma, but when there's a duplicate it's between two commas. There's a product description afterward so I can't just delete everything after a comma

Comment: Why can't you use `Right()` with a `Search()` for the comma? Then just return all info left of that comma?

Comment: You say "when there's a duplicate it's between two commas". Wouldn't that mean that you can just use replace and serach for ,*, and replace with a space or commar or nothing. Whatever you want to separate the part number and description?

Answer (score 0):

Two choices.

**1) Use Text to Columns to split the cells on comma characters:**

- Highlight the cells that could contain duplicates
- Open the Text to Columns tool on the Data tab.
- Choose "Delimited" on the first screen, click Next.
- Select the checkbox for "Comma" on the second screen, click Finish.

Everything before the comma will remain where it is; everything after the comma will be split into the next column. If there are any values in that column, they will be overwritten.

**2) Use Find and Replace:**

- Highlight the cells that could contain duplicates
- Open the Find and Replace tool on the Home | Find and Select tab, or press Ctrl+H
- In the Find box, enter ",*"
- Delete any value in the Replace box to leave it blank.
- Proceed with the replace.

This will search through the selected cells for commas followed by any string of characters, and will replace everything from the comma onward with an empty string, effectively deleting them.

**3) Use a Formula:**

- `=IFERROR(LEFT(A1,FIND(",",A1)-1),A1)`
- The Find function returns the location within a string where it finds a particular character or string.
- The Left function returns a specified number of characters from a string.

Good luck!